# Meaning of sticky pitch

Tags: cricket

What is the meaning of sticky pitch in cricket? Does it help the bowler or the batsmen? If it helps the bowler than which type of bowler? And where most of the sticky pitches are found in which part of the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sticky pitch or wicket is just a term for a pitch that has usually had some rain on it and so is damp and then dries out. This causes batting conditions that are tough because the dampness causes unpredictable bounce. Luckily, we don't get sticky wickets in modern cricket anymore with the advent of covers being necessary today.